# execute transaction failure - Liquidity Controller write function

Tags: gnosis-safe

We recently moved our liquidity controller contract to a gnosis safe and attempted to write a call function that fails with "Not a liquidity controller"

The assumption is that this is due to the wallet that is executing the transaction is sourcing from an owner to the multisig wallet?

Not sure if this is a common problem and if there are any suggestion remediation.

I have a tenderly error url that I can share privately.

Answer (score 1):

Disregard, we had to add the gnosis safe address as a lc on the contract.